# Bootstrap form linking to Google form, is there a way to record or get date using Bootstrap date picker to google form date picker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I am trying to make a form in website which will be connected to google form since i don't have any backend. I am getting form data by linking google forms. I have no problem in getting text and number inputs where as Date input is the place where am facing the problem. Bootstrap form has only one name field where as in google forms source code there were 3 name field inputs for DD , MM & YYYY.

```css
body {
background-color:#fdeffd!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row">

 <div class="col-5 position-relative">

      
      <h2 class="form-head text-dark text-center mb-0"><strong>Book your Free class</strong></h2>
      <p class="form-sub text-center text-muted">Learn From India's Top Architects</p>      
      <div class="form-group separator py-1 form-sub ">Enter Your Details</div>
      <form class="" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSfIZfSRkPIGK-Dqv1ha9giFrNdLzYswdyg6ZDxGz3Q8TmDcKg/formResponse">

        <div class="form-group col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="name" name="entry.247037541" autocomplete="off" required=""
            placeholder="Enter Name of Child">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col">
          <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="entry.194404824" placeholder="What is your Whatsapp Number" autocomplete="off" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group d-flex">
          <div class="col-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="entry.386356176" placeholder="which standard ?" required="" autocomplete="off"></div>
          <div class="col-6">
          <input type="text" placeholder="City" class="form-control form-control-sm col" name="entry.146726802" required="" autocomplete="off"></div>
        </div> 

<!---- problem are start --->
   
            <div class="form-group d-flex">              
              <div class="col">
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="date" name="" value="2011-08-19" id="example-date-input">                
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mt-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col">
              <button class="py-2 book-now-btn form-control text-light" type="submit" data-submit-button="" data-text="Book Now"><p class="mb-0 text-shadow">Schedule a Free Class</p></button>
          </div></div></div>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-5 text-center postion-relative"><a class="align-item-center" href="https://www.neramclasses.com">neramClasses.com Nata coaching center in chennai online</a></div></div>
    
    
    
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Google form source code for date which I wanna link to bootstrap form]